# Is patent US5715629 still in force?

Tags: usa, us5715629

Could you please tell me whether patent number US5715629 is still in force?

Answer (score 2):

The Application Data tab for this patent on the Public Patent Application Information Retrieval (PAIR) site (http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) indicates "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362"

Comment: You can also see this information reflected on the google patents page, at the bottom.